# How do I set a header in the login route so the browser remembers who is logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, jwt

**I've created a user login back end and everything works fine, but when I log in to a user detail, despite being correct, I'm unable to explore other routes because the user isn't authorized. how do I save the access token to the browser so it remembers?** This is the login route below.

```
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
try {
    const oneUser = await users.findOne({
        username: req.body.username,
    });

    if (!oneUser) {
        return res.status(500).json("User is not in the database");
    }

    const oPassword = cj.AES.decrypt(
        oneUser.password,
        process.env.pass
    ).toString(cj.enc.Utf8);

    if (oPassword !== req.body.password) {
        return res.status(500).json("Password is incorrect");
    }

    const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
            id: oneUser._id,
            isAdmin: oneUser.isAdmin,
        },
        process.env.jwtToken,
        { expiresIn: "300" }
    );

    const { password, ...others } = oneUser._doc;
    res.status(200).json({ ...others, accessToken });

} catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

});

I saw something like this on the net.

```
res.header("token", accessToken)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly, your `});` is outside the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can save a session for that user or response the token and save that to the client browser cookies or session store.

for setting session at node js app checkout link below
https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=session